# Load specific model from a glb file

Tags: javascript, three.js, model, 3d, webgl

Hello I am still quite inexperienced with ThreeJS and am just playing with it. I have looked at theverse tutorials and am already loading glb files and rendering them in the browser. This is all working very well.

I have loaded a GLB file from https://sketchfab.com/ in which 8 different human bodies are shown. I want to display only one body at a time depending on the situation.

My question is, is this possible ? Is it possible to select the individual models in the file and add them.  Or do I have to cut the glb file with e.g. Blender for this to work?

I tried to access with o.Children after loading the glb file but there was not this tried. Also, o.scene.length = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could just solve the problem myself

Here in this [a link](https://threejs.org/manual/#en/load-gltf) is described again how the file is loaded. There is also an example how to load single objects.

With the following command a single object can be selected:

```
 const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader();
  gltfLoader.load('resources/models/cartoon_lowpoly_small_city_free_pack/scene.gltf', (gltf) => {
    const root = gltf.scene;
    cars = root.getObjectByName('Cars');
    scene.add(cars)
});
```

With "scene.add(cars)" only this object is added now

Comment: So you load everything, and then display 1/8 of the file. Feels like a total waste of bandwidth...